# Solr 6 standalone - re-read security.json without restart

Tags: authentication, solr

Solr 6.6.4 is in use in standalone mode and based on https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#basic-authentication-plugin, `security.json` was created to protect the server. To be able to version control, it would be optimal to use `security.json` to add new users in the future.
Right now, to make Solr re-read `security.json`, I need to restart the service (the service was created by https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-solr).
Is there any way to force Solr to actualize the user DB after it was started?

I am aware of using the way outlined in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#BasicAuthenticationPlugin-AddaUserorEditaPassword , using the HTTP API, but to stick to the Ansible workflow, I'd like to keep all the changes in Git and happening via Ansible, that's why it's mandatory to do it via the configfile.

Comment: Is _any_ http call out of the question? I.e. an http call to reload the collection instead of restarting the service might be enough re-read the security.json file.

Comment: That would work. If the call does not contain the credentials we'd like to add, that works.

Comment: But reloading the core itself does not work, I tested that, it's on a higher level.